# Docker daemon image list duplicate IDs but different tags, where one of the image tags is "<none>"

Tags: docker, kube-solo

**Description**

Before I open a bug, I figured I should ask here - how can I cleanup a registry that has images with duplicate IDs with different tags, where one of the tags is `<none>`?

I apologize beforehand if this has been addressed elsewhere, and I'm just being ignorant. I've been googling and reading up on this for several days without luck.

```
REPOSITORY                                            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
registry                                              2                   541a6732eadb        2 days ago          33.27 MB
registry                                              <none>              541a6732eadb        2 days ago          33.27 MB
gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller                         v2.0.0-alpha.4      1000fa85b893        2 weeks ago         53.91 MB
gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller                         <none>              1000fa85b893        2 weeks ago         53.91 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64   v1.1.1              f739d2414b14        6 weeks ago         55.83 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64   <none>              f739d2414b14        6 weeks ago         55.83 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/kubedns-amd64                1.5                 3afb7dbce540        3 months ago        50.82 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/kubedns-amd64                <none>              3afb7dbce540        3 months ago        50.82 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/kube-dnsmasq-amd64           1.3                 9a15e39d0db8        3 months ago        5.126 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/kube-dnsmasq-amd64           <none>              9a15e39d0db8        3 months ago        5.126 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64                  3.0                 99e59f495ffa        4 months ago        746.9 kB
gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64                  <none>              99e59f495ffa        4 months ago        746.9 kB
gcr.io/google_containers/exechealthz-amd64            1.0                 82a141f5d06d        5 months ago        7.116 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/exechealthz-amd64            <none>              82a141f5d06d        5 months ago        7.116 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/heapster                     v0.18.5             8cadf3cdb46d        8 months ago        37.01 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/heapster                     <none>              8cadf3cdb46d        8 months ago        37.01 MB
gcr.io/google_containers/kubedash                     v0.2.1              624dae381b95        12 months ago       14.63 MB
```

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

I'm not sure how the registry got into this state

**Expected behavior**

One of several:

1. That the registry not be allowed to get into this state in the first place
2. Once it has reached this condition:
   a. Give me a way to tag the image with `<none>`.
   b. Give me a way to delete (`rmi`) the image with `<none>` tag.

**Output of `docker version`:**

```
Client:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 21:49:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.1
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   f1e1b83
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

**Output of `docker info`:**

```
Containers: 34
 Running: 12
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 22
Images: 9
Server Version: 1.12.1
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null overlay host bridge
Kernel Version: 4.7.3-coreos
Operating System: CoreOS 1164.1.0 (MoreOS)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 3
Total Memory: 7.801 GiB
Name: k8solo-01
ID: XKYE:K52Z:OV4I:VDF2:DNYD:BK2X:3C6S:CMUE:LNNX:HXQR:I7FO:ZWV6
```

**Additional environment details (AWS, VirtualBox, physical, etc.):**

`corectl` + `kube-solo` on Mac OS X El Capitan

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, there is no running registry info in your question, you are showing a image list of your local docker daemon. What is your registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have several images with duplicate IDs - the ID is unique, but the same image can have multiple tags. When tags are used for versioning, you'll often have the same image with several tags, for user convenience:

```
> docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              16.04               c73a085dc378        33 hours ago        127 MB
ubuntu              latest              c73a085dc378        33 hours ago        127 MB
ubuntu              xenial              c73a085dc378        33 hours ago        127 MB
```

I have a single image on this machine, which I can refer to with any of those tags.

The default image tag is `latest`, which is what you should see from `docker images` for images which have a repository name but no tag. If you run `docker rmi 541` you'll remove the `registry` image and both tags will be gone.

It's odd that you see `<none>` instead of `latest` though. On `1.12.1` if I run `docker pull` for the following image tags (using the Docker Hub):

```
registry:2
registry
kubernetes/heapster:v0.18.2
kubernetes/heapster
```

When they're all downloaded I see these entries from `docker images`:

```
registry              2                   541a6732eadb        4 days ago          33.3 MB
registry              latest              541a6732eadb        4 days ago          33.3 MB
kubernetes/heapster   latest              d2d2bfdfb48f        12 months ago       34.52 MB
kubernetes/heapster   v0.18.2             d2d2bfdfb48f        12 months ago       34.52 MB
```

As [Haoming Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/875882/haoming-zhang) says, what you're seeing is the contents of your local image cache, not the registry.

Comment: That makes sense to a degree - my question was informed by my ignorance - I thought I was looking at my registry, when instead I'm seeing the image list of my local docker daemon. That being said, does that image list look correct to you? From what you're saying, it does not. I've updated my question to focus on the docker image list.